# calc not working with stylus and grunt

Tags: css, gruntjs, stylus

I am stuck with a small problem.
I am trying to use calc function in stylus but it not working. I it giving wrong output always. I am using  grunt-contrib-stylus in grunt task runner.

when I am writting  `width: calc(100% - 100px);` is being generated as `width: calc(-300%);`.

I tried width: `'calc(100% - 100px)';`, `width: 'calc(100% \- 100px)';`, `width: calc(100% \- 100px);` but not worked.
Also tried:

```
calc(unquote('50% - 390px'))
calc(50% \- 390px)
```

solution given on : https://github.com/stylus/stylus/issues/687 it gives `calc(0)` as output.

My package.json contains "grunt-contrib-stylus": "~0.9.0". Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: what about this `width  "calc(100% - 100px)";`

Comment: Same result.  giving output as:   width: "calc(100% - 100px)";

Comment: Have you tried `width calc(100% - 100px)` (no colon, no semi-colon)?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known stylus problem. Use

```
calc(unquote('100% - 100px'))
```

> https://github.com/stylus/stylus/issues/687

Comment: Hi, Sorry to say that but I tried both solution: 
calc(unquote('50% - 390px'))
calc(50% \- 390px)
both giving calc(0)  as output.

Comment: I suggest you raise this as an issue on the grunt-contrib-stylus github repository then.

Comment: yep, sure. I thought I might get some solution. Thanks for suggestion @connexo